# "Залюбовавшись миражом" или "залюбовавшись на мираж"?

Tags: предлоги

Как грамотней: "Залюбовавшись миражом, не прозевай оазис" или "Залюбовавшись на мираж, не прозевай оазис". Может, оба эти предложения составлены неправильно? Не лучше ли будет: "любуясь миражом"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: Залюбовавшись миражом, не прозевай оазис.

ЗАЛЮБОВАТЬСЯ, св. **кем-чем**. Любуясь, заглядеться. З. морем. З. красивой девушкой.

**Примеры:**

В другое время можно бы залюбоваться этой полевой идиллией, но не теперь. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

Светило солнышко, и я в конце концов заставил себя залюбоваться этими камнями [Анатолий Эфрос. Профессия: режиссер (1975-1987)]

НО, возможно, раньше форма "залюбоваться на" также применялась:

С нашего прекрасного высока нельзя было не залюбоваться на неугомонный мировой Париж. [И. Е. Репин. Далекое близкое (1912-1917)]

Можно было бы залюбоваться на такую парочку! [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Благонамеренные речи (1872-1876)]

**Семантика глаголов "любоваться и залюбоваться" различается смысловыми оттенками** (любуясь, глядеть или заглядеться):  ЛЮБОВАТЬСЯ, **кем-чем** и (разг.) **на кого-что**. Рассматривать кого-, что-л. с восхищением, удовольствием.

Поэтому замена выражений не полностью сохраняет смысл сказанного.